# Javascript click and open new div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

what I'm trying to do for a long time is that; how can I open or create a new window using js button click. Example, I'm going to provide my simple quiz app code. I want to add a new button named "**Start**". If anyone click the button "**Start**", the quiz will be start. And the "Start" button will remove.

I've added a simple button for this purpose, but not removing the button after click "**Start**" button. How can I do it ?

My code example:

```js
$("#start-quiz").click(function(){
const
  rand = n => Math.floor(Math.random() * n),
  swap = (t, i, j) => { let q = t[i]; t[i] = t[j]; t[j] = q; return t; },
  shuffle = (arr = []) => {
    let copy = arr.slice(0, 2), last = copy.length, n;
    while (last > 0) { n = rand(last); swap(copy, n, --last); }
    return copy;
  };
  
var total_seconds = 1220 * 1;
var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
var timer;

function CheckTime() {
  document.getElementById("quiz-time-left1").innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;' + c_minutes + 'm' + ':' + c_seconds + 's';

  if (total_seconds <= 0) {
    score();
  } else {
    total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
    c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
    timer = setTimeout(CheckTime, 1000);
  }
}

timer = setTimeout(CheckTime, 1000);

const quizData = [{
  question: "Which language runs in a web browser?",
  a: "Java",
  b: "C",
  c: "Python",
  d: "JavaScript",
  correct: "d",
}, {
  question: "What does CSS stand for?",
  a: "Central Style Sheets",
  b: "Cascading Style Sheets",
  c: "Cascading Simple Sheets",
  d: "Cars SUVs Sailboats",
  correct: "b",
}, {
  question: "What does HTML stand for?",
  a: "Hypertext Markup Language",
  b: "Hypertext Markdown Language",
  c: "Hyperloop Machine Language",
  d: "Helicopters Terminals Motorboats Lamborginis",
  correct: "a",
}, {
  question: "What year was JavaScript launched?",
  a: "1996",
  b: "1995",
  c: "1994",
  d: "none of the above",
  correct: "b",
}, ];

const quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
const answerElements = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
const questionElement = document.getElementById("question");
const a_text = document.getElementById("a_text");
const b_text = document.getElementById("b_text");
const c_text = document.getElementById("c_text");
const d_text = document.getElementById("d_text");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

const randomizedQuestions = shuffle(quizData).slice(0, 10);
let currentQuestion = 0;
let score = 0;
const deselectAnswers = () => {
  answerElements.forEach((answer) => (answer.checked = false));
};
const getSelected = () => {
  let answer;
  answerElements.forEach((answerElement) => {
    if (answerElement.checked) answer = answerElement.id;
  });
  return answer;
};
const loadQuestion = () => {
  deselectAnswers();
  const currentQuestionData = randomizedQuestions[currentQuestion];
  questionElement.innerText = currentQuestionData.question;
  a_text.innerText = currentQuestionData.a;
  b_text.innerText = currentQuestionData.b;
  c_text.innerText = currentQuestionData.c;
  d_text.innerText = currentQuestionData.d;
};


loadQuestion();
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const answer = getSelected();
  if (answer) {
    if (answer === randomizedQuestions[currentQuestion].correct) score++;
    currentQuestion++;

    let asd = randomizedQuestions.length - score;
    let ssrate = (1220 - Math.floor(total_seconds));
    let ggg = "";

    if (ssrate < 12) ggg = "good morning";
    else if (ssrate < 16) ggg = "ghfgdfgh ning";
    else if (ssrate < 24) ggg = "asaasasasa   ng";

    let avg = Math.round(score * 100 / randomizedQuestions.length);

    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = avg;

    if (currentQuestion < randomizedQuestions.length) loadQuestion();
    else {
      // stop timer
      clearInterval(timer);

      quiz.innerHTML = "<h2>Total Question : " + quizData.length + "<br>" + "Correct Ans : " + score + " <br> Wrong Ans : " + asd + " <br> Average : " + avg + " %  <br> Time Usage : " + ssrate + " Seconds <br> Average : " + ggg + " %  <br><br>  <br><br> <button class='mi-ripple mi-ripple-light' onclick='location.reload()'>Play Again</button></h2>"

    }
  }
});
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #b8c6db;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #b8c6db 0%, #f5f7fa 100%);
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.quiz-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 95vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.quiz-header {
    padding: 4rem;
}

h2 {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

ul li label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button {
    background-color: #8e44ad;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 1.3rem;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #732d91;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #5e3370;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start-quiz"> Start </button>

    <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
        <div class="quiz-header">
            <h2 id="question">Question is loading...</h2>
             <div class="mi-center"  id="quiz-time-left1" ></div>
              <ul>
                <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a" class="answer" /> <label for="a" id="a_text">Answer...</label> </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b" class="answer" /> <label for="b" id="b_text">Answer...</label> </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="c" class="answer" /> <label for="c" id="c_text">Answer...</label> </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="d" class="answer" /> <label for="d" id="d_text">Answer...</label> </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <button id="submit" class="mi-ripple mi-ripple-light" >Submit</button>
    </div>
<progress id='myProgress' value='' max='100'>
```

To sum up, I want like that image: [image: Quiz Start Button]. When anyone will click on start button, the quiz will start. Like that: [image]

Comment: the div which you don't want to show you can add display;none  to it and then when chlick on start using jquery you can add class which will display it or you can style directly to display it using id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#start-quiz").click(function(){
// add class to quiz-container to show quiz container
$("#quiz").addClass("active");
// add class to start-quiz to hide start button
$("#start-quiz").addClass("active");
const
  rand = n => Math.floor(Math.random() * n),
  swap = (t, i, j) => { let q = t[i]; t[i] = t[j]; t[j] = q; return t; },
  shuffle = (arr = []) => {
    let copy = arr.slice(0, 2), last = copy.length, n;
    while (last > 0) { n = rand(last); swap(copy, n, --last); }
    return copy;
  };
  
var total_seconds = 1220 * 1;
var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
var timer;

function CheckTime() {
  document.getElementById("quiz-time-left1").innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;' + c_minutes + 'm' + ':' + c_seconds + 's';

  if (total_seconds <= 0) {
    score();
  } else {
    total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
    c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
    timer = setTimeout(CheckTime, 1000);
  }
}

timer = setTimeout(CheckTime, 1000);

const quizData = [{
  question: "Which language runs in a web browser?",
  a: "Java",
  b: "C",
  c: "Python",
  d: "JavaScript",
  correct: "d",
}, {
  question: "What does CSS stand for?",
  a: "Central Style Sheets",
  b: "Cascading Style Sheets",
  c: "Cascading Simple Sheets",
  d: "Cars SUVs Sailboats",
  correct: "b",
}, {
  question: "What does HTML stand for?",
  a: "Hypertext Markup Language",
  b: "Hypertext Markdown Language",
  c: "Hyperloop Machine Language",
  d: "Helicopters Terminals Motorboats Lamborginis",
  correct: "a",
}, {
  question: "What year was JavaScript launched?",
  a: "1996",
  b: "1995",
  c: "1994",
  d: "none of the above",
  correct: "b",
}, ];

const quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
const answerElements = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
const questionElement = document.getElementById("question");
const a_text = document.getElementById("a_text");
const b_text = document.getElementById("b_text");
const c_text = document.getElementById("c_text");
const d_text = document.getElementById("d_text");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

const randomizedQuestions = shuffle(quizData).slice(0, 10);
let currentQuestion = 0;
let score = 0;
const deselectAnswers = () => {
  answerElements.forEach((answer) => (answer.checked = false));
};
const getSelected = () => {
  let answer;
  answerElements.forEach((answerElement) => {
    if (answerElement.checked) answer = answerElement.id;
  });
  return answer;
};
const loadQuestion = () => {
  deselectAnswers();
  const currentQuestionData = randomizedQuestions[currentQuestion];
  questionElement.innerText = currentQuestionData.question;
  a_text.innerText = currentQuestionData.a;
  b_text.innerText = currentQuestionData.b;
  c_text.innerText = currentQuestionData.c;
  d_text.innerText = currentQuestionData.d;
};


loadQuestion();
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
$("#myProgress").addClass("active");
  const answer = getSelected();
  if (answer) {
    if (answer === randomizedQuestions[currentQuestion].correct) score++;
    currentQuestion++;

    let asd = randomizedQuestions.length - score;
    let ssrate = (1220 - Math.floor(total_seconds));
    let ggg = "";

    if (ssrate < 12) ggg = "good morning";
    else if (ssrate < 16) ggg = "ghfgdfgh ning";
    else if (ssrate < 24) ggg = "asaasasasa   ng";

    let avg = Math.round(score * 100 / randomizedQuestions.length);


    if (currentQuestion < randomizedQuestions.length) loadQuestion();
    else {
      // stop timer
      clearInterval(timer);

      quiz.innerHTML = "<h2>Total Question : " + quizData.length + "<br>" + "Correct Ans : " + score + " <br> Wrong Ans : " + asd + " <br> Average : " + avg + " %  <br> Time Usage : " + ssrate + " Seconds <br> Average : " + ggg + " %  <br><br>  <br><br> <button class='mi-ripple mi-ripple-light' onclick='location.reload()'>Play Again</button></h2><progress id='myProgress' value='"+avg+"' max='100'>"

    }
  }
});
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #b8c6db;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #b8c6db 0%, #f5f7fa 100%);
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.quiz-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 95vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:none;
}

.quiz-container.active{
    display:block;
}


.quiz-header {
    padding: 4rem;
}

h2 {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

ul li label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button {
    background-color: #8e44ad;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 1.3rem;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #732d91;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #5e3370;
}

#start-quiz.active{
display:none;
}

#myProgress{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start-quiz"> Start </button>

    <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
        <div class="quiz-header">
            <h2 id="question">Question is loading...</h2>
             <div class="mi-center"  id="quiz-time-left1" ></div>
              <ul>
                <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a" class="answer" /> <label for="a" id="a_text">Answer...</label> </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b" class="answer" /> <label for="b" id="b_text">Answer...</label> </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="c" class="answer" /> <label for="c" id="c_text">Answer...</label> </li>
                <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="d" class="answer" /> <label for="d" id="d_text">Answer...</label> </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <button id="submit" class="mi-ripple mi-ripple-light" >Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks. I really happy and the exact things I was looking for.

Comment: Another thins sister. Why progress bar not working on result page ?

I mean progress bar showing outside quiz div. I want show it in result page. Inside inner HTML area of JS. But when I implement inside innerHTML, it's not working. Can you please tell me why ?

Comment: if you want it inside .quiz-container then add progressbar inside that div. place it exactly where you want it. I changed above script and place it after submit button you can check.

Comment: Thanks for your approach, but I want to show the progress bar only when the quiz will complete. Thats mean result page, result page means where I can see my aquiz result. There I want to show it.

Comment: For that, I think you need to add in inside        () {
  .("--"). = 

   But when I add isnide innerHTML, its not working.

Comment: you can hide it using display: none and then change display:none to block on result page using jquery. like i did with #start-quiz and  .quiz-container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251321/discussion-between-asma-binta-younus-and-nisha).

Comment: check above script again. If you want it just in result then add in submit button so it will show there and remove from html page.

Comment: Awesome Man...., Alhamdulillah..... I really happy in your initial support.

Comment: I'm glad we were able to solve your problem today.

Comment: Hey @Nisha, It's showing on result page. That's true and good. But its not showing progress result..........!!!  In before, when it was outside, it shows progress result. But now it's not showing progress result. 

Comment: I edited above script again now check it

Comment: Now everything is OKKKKKKKKK.. Thanks.......

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#start-quiz").click(function(){

const thisElement = document.getElementById("start-quiz")
thisElement.remove()
.......
}
```